# PHP htmlspecialchars() used on form submitted data containing apostrophe, returns empty

Tags: php, forms, validation, htmlspecialchars, apostrophe

**PHP:** When a value containing an apostrophe comes from a form textfield the result is an empty string (Case 2 below)! But when the same value comes from the script itself, the result is at least a converted string (Case 1 below). This is an issue when validating form submission containing names with apostrophes with the htmlspecialchars() method. What else method could I use?

**Example:** textfield submitted with the text "Olé".

```
Case 1 (Result: "OlÃ©")
echo htmlspecialchars("Olé");

Case 2 (Result: "")
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["firstname"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You maybe want to use the `htmlentities()` function. This function can be used for utf-8 characters and more. It converts the special characters to HTML and display them normal.

Example:

```
<?php
$text = "Olé";
echo htmlentities($text);
?>
```

Output: **Olé**

Complete list of character-sets and examples can be viewed on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlentities.asp).

Comment: Thanks! Actually I want to store the name in a MySql database, and "Olé" should be stored as "Olé" and not OlÃ© or something else.

Comment: @David use `UTF-8` encoding to store the values in the database.